# Notification multiline

Tags: android, notifications

How to make a long notification multiline. I am using the below code snippet but its not working:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
  .setContentTitle(title)
  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
  .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
  .setContentText(message)
  .setContentIntent(pIntent);

return mBuilder.build();
```

Comment: Which sdk version are you targeting?

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

Comment: Multiline Notification supports from 4.1+ os. Check the link in answers section which I have provided.

Answer (score 131):

Add this :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context);
    Notification notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setContentText(message).build();

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Also check : [Multiline Notification](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html)

Comment: Works, details here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigTextStyle.html

Comment: Seems link is down. Here's how it was : https://web.archive.org/web/20190812093224/https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html

Comment: Could you explain what lines you added? First the lines do not have the same order as in the question, second you could use English to explain your solution rather than just writing unformatted unordered code.

Answer (score 12):

```
Bitmap icon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);  
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon()).setLargeIcon(icon1)
            .setTicker(title)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setTicker(message)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(title))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setContent(remoteViews)
             .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setVibrate(new long[] {1, 1, 1})
             .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
    NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notify = new Notification();
    notify.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
    Random random = new Random();
    notificationmanager.notify(random.nextInt(), builder.build());
```

Comment: setStyle is being called twice. Is it by mistake? if not, how does this work?

Comment: You can't use `bigTextStyle` twice, the second time will override the first one.
Title, Context, BigText those can be different values.
Big text shown if notification is expanded or user expand it himself

Answer (score 5):

Try this code working fine with android Oreo notification channel id.

```
public static int id = 0;
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {

    Log.d("FCMID","id : " + id);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    String channelId = "1";
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody))
            .setContentTitle("Piml Sid")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Spike Bot",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    id ++;
   notificationManager.notify(id /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `NotificationCompat.Builder` add

```
.setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(body))
.setContentText(body)
```

alnog with `.setContentText(body)`

Answer (score -2):

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
         .setContentTitle(title)  
         .setSmallIcon(icon) 
         .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(notificationMessage))
         .setAutoCancel(true)
         .setContentIntent(intent)
         .build();
```

Comment: The code of `setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle()` has to be `setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()`. Otherwise it throws an error as `BigTextStyle cannot be converted to Style`.